# Interpolating coordinates by a 200ms time-step in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is a 2D array that represents movement of an entity over a 2 second period:

```
[[10, 200, 0], [70, 170, 600], [110, 150, 1000], [155, 120, 1600], [155, 120, 2000]]
```

Each array elements contains x-coordinate, y-coordinate, and timestamp in such order.

I need to transform this data which shows location at sporadic moments in time to an array showing the location at a fixed rate of every 200ms. I need to interpolate the missing values.

I know the correct output is:

```
10  200 0
30  190 200
50  180 400 
70  170 600
90  160 800
110 150 1000
125 140 1200
140 130 1400
155 120 1600
155 120 1800
155 120 2000
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems pretty basic. What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: How from using array : [[10, 200, 0], [70, 170, 600], [110, 150, 1000], [155, 120, 1600], [155, 120, 2000]] do I print the required O/P?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINAL EDIT HOPEFULLY**
I think I understand the question now thanks to @j08691 and @ISAE

**EDIT** @Gershy pointed out that the 200ms step asked was hardcoded into my solution so I changed it to a variable.

Here is the  [NEW JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sloont/mhtscj9w/38/).

Here is the code:

```js
const data = [
  [10, 200, 0],
  [70, 170, 600],
  [110, 150, 1000],
  [155, 120, 1600],
  [155, 120, 2000]
];
const STEP = 200;
// log the starting position first
console.log("" + data[0][0] + " " + data[0][1] + " " + data[0][2] + "\n")
for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
  const array1 = data[i];
  const array2 = data[i + 1];
  //find how many updates you need to print for each comparison
  const n = ((array2[2] - array1[2]) / STEP);
  const xMovement = (array2[0] - array1[0]) / n;
  const yMovement = (array2[1] - array1[1]) / n;
  for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    console.log("" + (array1[0] + xMovement * j) + " " +
      (array1[1] + yMovement * j) + " " +
      (array1[2] + STEP * j) + "\n");
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Ok I confused myself and others with this one a lot so I worked all of the way through it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bs4g3rq/3/).

I definitely works now.

**___________**

The problem just wants you to iterate through the 2D Array and log it to the console.

I don't want to do your homework for you but you'll need nested loops to iterate each and print. When you get to the end of an inner array, print a newline character as well. [this was rude...sry]

**EDIT**
Ok since someone downvoted me, here you go:

The iteration:

```js
const data = [
  [10, 200, 0],
  [70, 170, 600],
  [110, 150, 1000],
  [155, 120, 1600],
  [155, 120, 2000]
];
let n = 0
data.forEach(array => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let line = ""
    array.forEach(item => line += item + " ");
    console.log(line + "\n");
  }, n += 200);
})
```

Comment: It wants a log the movement **at every 200 ms** not just a loop and log

Comment: @ISAE yeah my bad I misread that. This solution should do it, yeah?

Comment: @ISAE it did not when I posted it, but it has been edited now to work properly.

Comment: It's not about timeout either, it's a calculation thing. See my answer.

Comment: Look at the output in the question. You don't need seTimeout at all. You need to calculate the missing values. 0, 200ms, 400ms, 600ms.

Comment: @j0869 I finally understand. Would have replied sooner but was testing the JSFiddle. I prepended my answer with the correct solution and have left everything else as it documents what working through a problem can be like. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This happens to work, but will fail if any of the entries has a milliseconds value that isn't an exact multiple of `200`. A very brittle solution.

Comment: @Gershy great point. forgot I hard-coded the 200. I will add it in as a variable.

Comment: @sloont adding as a variable won't solve your problem. Your code requires all time steps between entries in the array to share a common multiple (because the variable you named `n` is always expected to be an integer).

Comment: @Gershy yeah you make a great point. I do think that's a bit above the scope and difficulty of the original question. Obviously your method is going to be better and more scalable. I think this is just someones classwork though.

Comment: @sloont no doubt you've solved the OP's exact question. On stackoverflow you should consider that anyone may stumble over your answer. If your answer only works on the OP's exact use-case, it won't generalize to help other people. Providing general solutions that can help many people is the purpose of this site - not solving homework problems! :)

Comment: @Gershy Yeah that's a really great point. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The assessment is asking you to **calculate the movement** of elements for every 200ms period.
Taking the first and second elements for example, you have: `[10, 200, 0], [70, 170, 600]` which means that at the start (0ms) the element is in XY position of 10 & 200 respectively. after 600ms (2nd element) it is in XY position of 70 & 170. So the element has moved 60 X points (70 - 10) and -30 Y points (200 - 170).
You'll need to find the ms difference between each element and the next, find it's divisor to 200ms blocks, and calculate the position it should be at each 200ms.
To continue with the example, the difference between element 1 and 2 in ms (3rd number in the element) is 600ms which is 3 200ms blocks, so 60 X points divide to 3 (3 200ms steps) is 20. adding the start position of 10, you'll get 30, 50 and 70. -30 Y points divides into -10 movement in each 200ms timeframe, so it'll be 190, 180 and 170. And so on.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't understand. What exactly is going on?

Comment: The array is **describing the movement of a (theoretical) element** along the XY axis at a specific speed. each element in the array contains 3 numbers: X position, Y position and the time elapsed since start. Based on those numbers, your task is to calculate where the (virtual) element should be at every 200 ms.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of *interpolation*. We need to log the position every 200ms. Consider the 600th millisecond; it is very easy to log, because there is an entry for exactly the 600th millisecond - but the 800th millisecond is not as trivial, as it lands between the entries for 600ms and 1000ms. How do we log it? We take a weighted average of the two surrounding values. Note that this is called a "linear interpolation" (and is only one of several ways of filling in blanks in a dataset).

The following `interpolate` function allows any sequence to be interpolated using any timestep. The only restriction is that the `data` array must be sorted in ascending order by its millisecond value (already the case for your data).

```js
let data = [
  [10, 200, 0],
  [70, 170, 600],
  [110, 150, 1000],
  [155, 120, 1600],
  [155, 120, 2000]
];

let interpolate = (data, stepSize=200) => {
  
  let result = [];
  for (let ms = 0; true; ms += stepSize) {
    
    // Find the two entries to either side of the current `ms`
    // E.g. if current `ms` is 800, should return the 600ms and
    // 1000ms entries. If `ms` is exactly equal to a particlar
    // entry, `e1` and `e2` are *both* set to that entry.
    // If we can't find both an entry before and after, return
    // `null` for both entries.
    let [ e1, e2 ] = (() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        
        // Can an exact match be found?
        if (data[i][2] === ms)
          return [ data[i], data[i] ];
        
        // Do consecutive entries contain the current `ms`?
        if (data[i + 1] && data[i][2] < ms && data[i + 1][2] > ms)
          return [ data[i], data[i + 1] ];
        
      }
      return [ null, null ];
    })();
        
    // Stop once no more entries can be found
    if (e1 === null) break;
    
    // Get the distance between entries
    let msDist = e2[2] - e1[2];
    
    if (msDist === 0) {
      
      // Handle an exact match by including the exact entry
      result.push([ ...e1 ]);
      
    } else {
    
      // Handle moments between entries with an interpolated
      // average:
      
      // Get distance between `e1` and `ms`, and between `e2`
      // and `ms`
      let dist1 = ms - e1[2];
      let dist2 = e2[2] - ms;
      
      // Take the interpolated average. The bigger `dist2` is
      // the more `e1` plays into the value. The bigger
      // `dist1` is, the more `e2` plays into the value.
      let mult1 = 1 - (dist1 / msDist);
      let mult2 = 1 - (dist2 / msDist);
      result.push([ e1[0] * mult1 + e2[0] * mult2, e1[1] * mult1 + e2[1] * mult2, ms ]);
      
    }
    
  }
  
  return result;
  
};

// Do the interpolation
let interpolated = interpolate(data);

// Log the resulting items
console.log(interpolated.map(([ x, y, ms ]) =>
  `${ms}ms: (${Math.round(x)}, ${Math.round(y)})`
));
```